# SliverPersistentHeader with ListViewBuilder causing strange scrolling issue

Tags: flutter, dart

You can see the issue in this gif:
[image: Issue gif]

And here's the code and example:
https://dartpad.dev/2cc7714328ad1c44d5fccabe7a73eb7a

I have this same setup in my app and it's causing issues when the users scrolls down then back up then down (without waiting for the bounce to settle)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:https://dartpad.dev/4b8df2bed9db58fbdf16dd041362ee22

This issue was due to using a ListViewBuilder under a sliver. It was fixed by using a SliverList widget instead, you can see the difference here:

Before:

```
NestedScrollView(
  headerSliverBuilder:
      (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
    return <Widget>[
      SliverPersistentHeader(
        pinned: true,
        //? M7: this was true
        //floating: false, // useless if pinned is true.
        delegate: ContestTabHeader(
            (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1)),
        //(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1.3)),
      ),
    ];
  },
  body: Container(
    color: AppTheme.getTheme().backgroundColor,
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 4,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 32, bottom: 16),
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        var count = 4;
        var animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
          CurvedAnimation(
            parent: widget.animationController,
            curve: Interval((1 / count) * index, 1.0,
                curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
          ),
        );
        if (index == 0) {
          return TitleView(
            titleTxt: 'المواضيع',
            subTxt: '',
            animation: animation,
            animationController: widget.animationController,
          );
        } else if (index == 1) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
            child: PopularListView(
              animationController:
                  widget.animationController,
              callBack: (index) {},
            ),
          );
        } else if (index == 2) {
          return TitleView(
            titleTxt: 'ننصحك بهذه الدروس',
            subTxt: 'View all',
            animation: animation,
            isLeftButton: true,
            animationController: widget.animationController,
          );
        } else {
          return getDealListView(index);
        }
      },
    ),
  ),
),
```

Then after the fix:

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverPersistentHeader(
      pinned: false,
      // floating: false,
      delegate: ContestTabHeader((MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1)),
    ),
    SliverPadding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                              sliver: SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (context, index) {
            var count = 4;
            var animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
              CurvedAnimation(
                parent: widget.animationController,
                curve: Interval((1 / count) * index, 1.0, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
              ),
            );
            if (index == 0) {
              return TitleView(
                titleTxt: 'المواضيع',
                subTxt: '',
                animation: animation,
                animationController: widget.animationController,
              );
            } else if (index == 1) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                child: PopularListView(
                  animationController: widget.animationController,
                  callBack: (index) {},
                ),
              );
            } else if (index == 2) {
              return TitleView(
                titleTxt: 'ننصحك بهذه الدروس',
                subTxt: 'View all',
                animation: animation,
                isLeftButton: true,
                animationController: widget.animationController,
              );
            } else {
              return getDealListView(index);
            }
          },
          childCount: 4,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Hope this helps someone that's facing the same problem.